# Exists a Unity Service to save server Specif data?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want integrate a trading system in my unity Game. So that player can trade ther items with other players. But therfore i must safe a List on server, where every trade offer is listed. And the player can read that list. I can't find a specific unity service for that. Or could i use cloud save in a such way, I create a "player "on server and write in player entry my informations. But that feels not the wright way. So should i do that? Or what ideas do you have? or Should i switch to google or amazon or Microsoft???

Or could i use cloud code and then connect to a sql sever?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a server that holds a database of the available trades, and during the game a player fetches the information from there using basic HTTP requests.

If you do this just make sure to plan carefully everything as it may lead to security flaws/cheats/exploits.